# Hide table view when someone clicks on a button in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4

I have 2 buttons in the header of tableView1. I want it so that when people click either button, two things  happen:

tableView1 disappears

tableView2 shows up

or

tableView1 shows up

tableView2 disappears

how can I do that using IOS?

I tried doing the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"tableheader_01.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 159, 57);
        button.tag = 7;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(hideTable:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button2 setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"tableheader_02.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button2.frame = CGRectMake(159, 0, 161, 57);
        button2.tag = 7;
        [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(hideTable:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.contentView addSubview: button];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: button2];
```

Where the hideTable has the following code:

```
-(IBAction) hideTable : (id) sender;
{
    NSLog(@"test");

    [self.myTableView1 setHidden:YES];
    [self.myTableView2 setHidden:NO];
}
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Can you show how you are setting myTableView1 and myTableView2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many possibilities to implement such UI.

1.Either you can keep both buttons outside or above both tables.So that if you click on button1 you hide first table & show second & when click on second hide second table & show first table.

OR

2.In first table add two button at first row as you did.When you click on button1 then instead of hiding first table return 1 for table1 data source in numberofrows method & reload table1, so that buttons will be there & then show second table below first table.When user click on second button then hide second table & return new data source for first table & reload table1.

OR

3.Use one table for both data source.At first row there will be two buttons.On clicking on them reload table accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single table view and just change the data source when a button is clicked, then reload the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the self.myTableView1.datasource = nil and when you need to use it, you can set self.myTableView1.datasource = self and [self.myTableView1 reloaddata]